# How to choose between one-way, two-anova and multliple regression?

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, anova

I am working on the data set that consists of Patients' id (after stroke), Time (they can walk after going through the program), the Program they follow and the Visit number when the Time was measured.

```
Patient   Program   Time(walking)   Visit(Check)
1           P1       12             Day 10
2           P3       23             Day 5
3           P3       8              Day 1
4           P2       36             Day 10
5           P1       10             Day 1
6           P2       86             Day 10
...
380           P1       13             Day 5
```

I am investigating whether **there is evidence that the effects of different programs differ over time?**

**My approach** was to consider the ANOVA test for the response variable Time (effect) and the Independent variable Program. In such a way:

```
new <- aov(Time~Programme, dane)
> summary(new)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Programme    2  398.4   199.2    0.61   0.58
Residuals    5 1633.5   326.7
```

But I am hesitant now about the fact that maybe the **Visit column should be somehow included** in this investigation?. Shall I use a different method to come up with an answer to that question **(ex. regression? two-way ANOVA?)**

Comment: This seems to be repeated-measurements data. Consider add the tag [tag:repeated-measures]: Also, is this time in minutes? Sample size? Some more details will help!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The time is in minutes, the sample size = number of patients.

Comment: But how many patients? Have you shown us all you have, I guessed it was a small selection!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen 380 patients, sorry!

Comment: Please add all this new information as an edit to the post, we want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overlooked!